# Program collapses at await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have programmed a light bulb production simulation in C#. When a user enters option 1 in the command line interface, an asynchronous function starts simulating the production of 10,000 light bulbs, with 5% of all bulbs being defective. When a defective bulb is detected, an observer is notified and a message is displayed in the command prompt. In the new solution, I tried to avoid the fire-and-forget problem. Instead, I collect the tasks in a list. The results of the tasks can be evaluated with option 2. To do this, await must be used to wait for the tasks to finish. Unfortunately, the program collapses in the main method when the user enters option 2. Can someone tell me why?

```
Console.WriteLine("Bulb Production Monitoring!");
Main();
static async Task Main() {
    List<Task<string>> taskList = new List<Task<string>>();
    string input="";
    int maschineID=1;
    Random rndGenerator = new Random();
    Production prod=new Production();
    Console.WriteLine("1: starts a production maschine");
    Console.WriteLine("2: analyses the results");
    Console.WriteLine("3: exits the production process");
    while(!input.Equals("exit")){
        input=Console.ReadLine();
        switch(input){
            case "1": 
                prod.registerObserver(new Observer());
                taskList.Add(prod.startMaschine(maschineID, rndGenerator)); 
                maschineID++; 
                break;
            case "2":
                // while tasklist contains an element
                while (taskList.Any()){

                    // waiting for a Task
                    Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
                    // gets the message of the task
                    Console.WriteLine($"{finishedTask.Result}");
                    // remove the Task
                    taskList.Remove(finishedTask);
                }
                break;
            case "3" : input="exit"; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}

public class Bulb{
    public bool _functionTest;
}

public class Production{
    private List<Observer> _observerList = new List<Observer>();
    public async Task<string> startMaschine(int maschineId, Random rndGenerator){
        return await Task.Run(
            async ()=>{
                Console.WriteLine($"Maschine {maschineId} is ready for use ... ");
                int i=0;
                int defect=0;
                while(i<10000){
                    int rndNumber=rndGenerator.Next(1,101);
                    Bulb bulb = new Bulb();
                    await Task.Delay(50);
                    if (rndNumber<=5){
                        bulb._functionTest=false;
                        defect++;
                        this.notify(maschineId);
                    }else{bulb._functionTest=true;}
                }
                return $"Maschine {maschineId} has produced {defect} bulbs.";
            }
        );
    }

    public void registerObserver(Observer obs){
        _observerList.Add(obs);
    }

    private void notify(int maschineId){
        foreach(Observer obs in _observerList){
            obs.update(maschineId);
        }
    }
}

public class Observer{
    public void update(int maschineId){
        DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine($"Defect bulb identified on maschine {maschineId} at {localDate}.");
    }
}
```

### Edit:

For the statement `Task<string> finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);` debugging terminates without error message. All other breakpoints are ignored.

Comment: What exactly does "the program collapses" mean?  In what specific way does the code fail?  What debugging observations have you made?

Comment: I am guessing you mean it crashes due to an unhandled exception when you wrote "Program collapses"?  [We need ALL Exception details to help you](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Please always try to describe the observed behavior with as much detail as possible. This is the first time I have read/heard anyone use "collapse" to describe behavior not related to a GUI control.

Comment: You can also look in your computer's Event Viewer. I am guessing .NET is writing details of the crash to the log. Please share them with us.

Comment: There is no error message. The program terminates when the user enters a 2 after entering 1. Breakpoints are ignored. To me it looks like the program terminates in a regular way, which is impossible.

Comment: Hint: don't ignore warnings in the future. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To me it looks like the program terminates in a regular way, which is impossible.

That's *exactly* what's happening - it's not impossible, it's entirely predictable.

You should be getting a warning at compile-time which tells you exactly the problem:

> warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

That's on line 6, the call to `Main()`. You're calling an async method, but ignoring the returned task... which means as soon as `Main` reaches the first await expression which has to wait for a continuation, it returns to the caller, and the code exits.

You could fix this by just awaiting the task:

```cs
await Main();
```

Or just remove the `Main()` call entirely and the declaration of `Main`... just let the whole of your `Main` method be top-level statements, and the compiler will recognize that it needs to handle it asynchronously.

---

If you want to see this demonstrated in a more obvious way, consider the code below - which doesn't use top-level statements, in order to make everything as straightforward as possible.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main 1");
        AsyncMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("Main 2");
    }
    
    static async Task AsyncMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncMethod 1");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncMethod 2");
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Main 1
AsyncMethod 1
Main 2
```

The program exits before `AsyncMethod 2` is ever printed, because `AsyncMethod` returns (with a task representing the overall operation) when it gets to `await Task.Delay(2000)`.